# Python: How to convert a set of strings that contains commas represented as an element of a list to a sub-list?

Tags: python

I have a list that contains a set of strings like this:

```
list = ['235,ACCESS,19841136,22564960,4291500,20,527434,566876','046,ALLOWED,24737321,27863065,1086500,3,14208500,14254500']
```

I'm trying to make the elements of the list a sublist but without splitting the string.

I tried `new_list = list(map(list, list))`. This is the result taking as reference the first element of the list:

```
print(new_list[0]):
[['2', '3', '5', ',', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'E', 'S',',','1', '9', '8', '4', '1', '1', '3', '6', ',', '2', '2', '5', '6', '4', '9', '6', '0', ',', '4', '2', '9', '1', '5', '0', '0', ',', '2', '0', ',', '5', '2', '7', '4', '3', '4', ',', '5', '6', '6', '8', '7', '6']]
```

I would like this output:

```
print(new_list[0]):
[[235,'ACCESS',19841136,22564960,4291500,20,527434,566876]]
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `[[235,ACCESS,19841136,22564960,4291500,20,527434,566876]]` this is not valid. You meant `[[235,"ACCESS",19841136,22564960,4291500,20,527434,566876]]`?

Comment: Sorry about that kuro, that is correct.

Comment: What do you mean "without splitting the string"?  The result you desire is exactly what [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) does.

Comment: This is a programming exercise? Normally split, re.split and csv.reader are tools for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `split()` with delimiter `,` like this -

```
new_list = [i.split(',') for i in list]
print (new_list[0])
```

Output:

```
['235', 'ACCESS', '19841136', '22564960', '4291500', '20', '527434', '566876']
```

One thing is that here the numbers are also represented as string. If you want integers instead you can use `isdigit()` method like this -

```
new_list = [[int(e) if e.isdigit() else e for e in i.split(',') ]for i in list]
print(new_list[0])
```

Output:

```
[235, 'ACCESS', 19841136, 22564960, 4291500, 20, 527434, 566876]
```

Also, please try to avoid naming your list `list`